# A $3$ digit number which is equal to its sum of product of digits plus sum of digits.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know the $2$ digit solution but  what about $3$ digits. Like for $2$ digit 
Its 
$10x+y=(xy)+(x+y)$.

Comment: There is none...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $100a+10b+c=ab+bc+ca+abc$ where $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2, \cdots , 9 \}$ ... is that what you want ?

Comment: I want 100a+10b+c=(a+b+c)+(a*b*c)... Where a,b,c{0,1,2....9}

Comment: @Arya this is your second of two post on MSE in which you haven't shown your work.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\bar{abc}^{10}$ be such a number.

If i translate the problem, the equation can be written:

$$ 100a +10b+c=abc+a+b+c$$

which is equivalent to

$$99a +9b=abc \Leftrightarrow (99-bc)a+9b=0$$

As $bc \leq 9*9 $, $ 99-bc > 0$ meaning necessarily $a=b=0$.

If you work with one-digit numbers, then if you allow to write them with $0$'s upfront, the solutions would be : $000, 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008 $ and $009$.